# Display Percentage Beside Heading in Body

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

im new to learning Javascript, Jquery and HTML. Im trying to display/show the Total Average in the heading (beside it) and not in the dataset table. I tried different methods but it wont show. (The last method I tried to work with is what in including in the codes.
i tried <div class=">,  but nothing seems to be working

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let doc, htm, bod, nav, M, I, S, Q, hC, aC, rC, tC; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', () => {
  doc = document;
  htm = doc.documentElement;
  bod = doc.body;
  nav = navigator;
  M = tag => doc.createElement(tag);
  I = id => doc.getElementById(id);
  mobile = /Mobi/i.test(nav.userAgent);
  S = (selector, within) => {
    let w = within || doc;
    return w.querySelector(selector);
  }
  Q = (selector, within) => {
    let w = within || doc;
    return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
  }
  hC = (node, className) => {
    return node.classList.contains(className);
  }
  aC = (node, ...classNames) => {
    node.classList.add(...classNames);
    return aC;
  }
  rC = (node, ...classNames) => {
    node.classList.remove(...classNames);
    return rC;
  }
  tC = (node, className) => {
    node.classList.toggle(className);
    return tC;
  }
  // small Library above - magic below can be put on another page using a load Event *(except // end load line)*
  const trs = Q('tbody>tr'),
    trsL = trs.length,
    prs = Q('tfoot>tr>td+td'),
    prsM = prs.length - 1,
    ya = [];

  function showAverages() {

    let total = 0;
    for (let p = 0, c, t, l = ya.length; p < prsM; p++) {
      c = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        c += ya[i][p];
      }
      t = (c / l * 100).toFixed(2);
      prs[p].textContent = t;
      total += (+t);
    }
    prs[prsM].textContent = (total / prsM).toFixed(2);
    var element = document.getElementById(prs[prsM]);
  }

  for (let i = 0, r, sels, y; i < trsL; i++) {
    r = trs[i];
    sels = Q('select', r);
    ya.push([]);
    for (let n = 0, s, q = sels.length; n < q; n++) {
      s = sels[n];
      s.value = 'Yes';
      y = s.value === 'Yes' ? 1 : 0;
      ya[i].push(y);
      s.oninput = () => {
        ya[i][n] = s.value === 'Yes' ? 1 : 0;
        showAverages();
      }
    }
  }

  showAverages();
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */

* {
  /* set font-size separate to avoid white space issues */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  font: italic 16px Georgia, Garamond, serif;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

thead *,
tfoot * {
  font: bold 16px Arial, san-serif;
}

tbody * {
  font: 15px Arial, sans-serif;
}

td,
th {
  width: 90px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #ddd;
}

tfoot>tr>td:not(:first-child):after {
  content: '%';
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8' />
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
  <title>Finding Average</title>

</head>

<body>

  <p>Finding and Display Average: <span id="element"></span></p>
  <!--the total average goes here-->
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Jan</th>
        <th>Feb</th>
        <th>Mar</th>
        <th>Apr</th>
        <th>May</th>
        <th>Jun</th>
        <th>Jul</th>
        <th>Aug</th>
        <th>Sept</th>
        <th>Oct</th>
        <th>Nov</th>
        <th>Dec</th>
        <th>Total Average</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr class="percent_row">
        <td>Response Percent</td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Bought Office Supplies</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Saving's Over $25,000</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Savings</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Over Budget</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Over Budget $10,000</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Over Budget $20,000</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: hum..its not clear,  what do you mean by *i want to display total average in the heading*?   could you display the result you want?

Comment: Sorry for confusion... at the moment I’m calculating and finding average. I’m calculating all the month from month January to December in the very last row called Response Percent and the result of the calculation same response percent) in under notes. So basically whatever the result is showing in the very last column total average  I want to remove from there and want to show it beside the heading

Comment: i understant you dont want to display total average in last column but i dont understant *beside the heading* so  do you want to display total average before the column *Jan*? or you just speak about the last row in the last column?

Comment: do you want to display the value of total average (of the last column and last row) after *Finding and Display Average:*?

Comment: Yes I tried <div> method and the Las test I tried <span> method but doesn’t show

Comment: ok see my answer, you have a problem of font size!!

Comment: ok that is why it was not showing

Comment: i have modified my answer to show your result..  i have included it in the loop  *$("#element").html(prs[prsM].textContent + "%");*

Comment: aahh i see now got it..you are on true genius... thank you

Comment: i have a question but im not sure if it will make sense:

Comment: its better to write  *$("#element").html((total / prsM).toFixed(2) + "%");*  if you dont want to use the last column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i have understood your problem.

so in your CSS you have defined a `font {size:0.....`    its normal you dont see the result! so i have added a `p span` css declaration

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let doc, htm, bod, nav, M, I, S, Q, hC, aC, rC, tC; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', () => {

  doc = document;
  htm = doc.documentElement;
  bod = doc.body;
  nav = navigator;
  M = tag => doc.createElement(tag);
  I = id => doc.getElementById(id);

  mobile = /Mobi/i.test(nav.userAgent);
  S = (selector, within) => {
    let w = within || doc;
    return w.querySelector(selector);
  }
  Q = (selector, within) => {
    let w = within || doc;
    return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
  }
  hC = (node, className) => {
    return node.classList.contains(className);
  }
  aC = (node, ...classNames) => {
    node.classList.add(...classNames);
    return aC;
  }
  rC = (node, ...classNames) => {
    node.classList.remove(...classNames);
    return rC;
  }
  tC = (node, className) => {
    node.classList.toggle(className);
    return tC;
  }
  // small Library above - magic below can be put on another page using a load Event *(except // end load line)*
  const trs = Q('tbody>tr'),
    trsL = trs.length,
    prs = Q('tfoot>tr>td+td'),
    prsM = prs.length - 1,
    ya = [];

  function showAverages() {

    let total = 0;
    for (let p = 0, c, t, l = ya.length; p < prsM; p++) {
      c = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        c += ya[i][p];
      }
      t = (c / l * 100).toFixed(2);
      prs[p].textContent = t;
      total += (+t);
    }
    prs[prsM].textContent = (total / prsM).toFixed(2);
    var element = document.getElementById(prs[prsM]);
    $("#element").html((total / prsM).toFixed(2) + "%");
  }

  for (let i = 0, r, sels, y; i < trsL; i++) {
    r = trs[i];
    sels = Q('select', r);
    ya.push([]);
    for (let n = 0, s, q = sels.length; n < q; n++) {
      s = sels[n];
      s.value = 'Yes';
      y = s.value === 'Yes' ? 1 : 0;
      ya[i].push(y);
      s.oninput = () => {
        ya[i][n] = s.value === 'Yes' ? 1 : 0;
        showAverages();
      }
    }
  }

  showAverages();



});
```

```css
/* css/external.css */

* {
  /* set font-size separate to avoid white space issues */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  font: italic 16px Georgia, Garamond, serif;
}

/* added ---------- */
p span {
 color:black;
 font : bold 16px Georgia, Garamond, serif;
}
/* ---------------- */

table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

thead *,
tfoot * {
  font: bold 16px Arial, san-serif;
}

tbody * {
  font: 15px Arial, sans-serif;
}

td,
th {
  width: 90px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #ddd;
}

tfoot>tr>td:not(:first-child):after {
  content: '%';
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8' />
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
  <title>Finding Average</title>

</head>

<body>
<div>
  <p>Finding and Display Average: <span id="element"></span><br><br><br></p></div>
  <!--the total average goes here-->
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Jan</th>
        <th>Feb</th>
        <th>Mar</th>
        <th>Apr</th>
        <th>May</th>
        <th>Jun</th>
        <th>Jul</th>
        <th>Aug</th>
        <th>Sept</th>
        <th>Oct</th>
        <th>Nov</th>
        <th>Dec</th>
        <th>Total Average</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr class="percent_row">
        <td>Response Percent</td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Bought Office Supplies</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Saving's Over $25,000</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Savings</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Over Budget</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Over Budget $10,000</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Over Budget $20,000</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: so basically instead of 12345 i just replace it with "prs[p].textContent = t;
      total += (+t);" since this show the value of total average (of the last column and last row)

Comment: you replace"12345"  by the variable which contents the final result  (without quotes)

Comment: please dont forget to validate and upvote to close the question..

Comment: Also i wanted to to add a function that every the user refresh, reload or even close the page i want the data whatever they choose in the <select> stays on the webpage

Comment: to remove % from last row and last colum modify your css: *tfoot>tr>td:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):after {
  content: '%';
  font-weight: bold;
}*    (added last child to the line containing firstchild)

Comment: Also i wanted to to add a function that every the user refresh, reload or even close the page i want the data whatever they choose in the <select> stays on the webpage

Comment: for your last question i suggest you to re-ask another question to avoid confusion with the actual question..  one problem one question

Comment: got it and thank you and i make a question right now

Comment: ok i have upload the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67037864/save-the-input-the-user-make-even-after-reload-refresh-or-close-the-webapge