# Save the input the user make even after reload/refresh

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I wanted to to add a function that every time the user refresh, reload or even close the page, the user to able to see the data whatever the user had entered previously  or choose in the `<select>`.

Also when the user make an update and refresh they show be able to see the change.

```js
let doc, htm, bod, nav, M, I, S, Q, hC, aC, rC, tC; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', () => {

  doc = document;
  htm = doc.documentElement;
  bod = doc.body;
  nav = navigator;
  M = tag => doc.createElement(tag);
  I = id => doc.getElementById(id);

  mobile = /Mobi/i.test(nav.userAgent);
  S = (selector, within) => {
    let w = within || doc;
    return w.querySelector(selector);
  }
  Q = (selector, within) => {
    let w = within || doc;
    return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
  }
  hC = (node, className) => {
    return node.classList.contains(className);
  }
  aC = (node, ...classNames) => {
    node.classList.add(...classNames);
    return aC;
  }
  rC = (node, ...classNames) => {
    node.classList.remove(...classNames);
    return rC;
  }
  tC = (node, className) => {
    node.classList.toggle(className);
    return tC;
  }
  // small Library above - magic below can be put on another page using a load Event *(except // end load line)*
  const trs = Q('tbody>tr'),
    trsL = trs.length,
    prs = Q('tfoot>tr>td+td'),
    prsM = prs.length - 1,
    ya = [];

  function showAverages() {

    let total = 0;
    for (let p = 0, c, t, l = ya.length; p < prsM; p++) {
      c = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        c += ya[i][p];
      }
      t = (c / l * 100).toFixed(2);
      prs[p].textContent = t;
      total += (+t);
    }
    prs[prsM].textContent = (total / prsM).toFixed(2);
    var element = document.getElementById(prs[prsM]);
    $("#element").html((total / prsM).toFixed(2) + "%");
  }

  for (let i = 0, r, sels, y; i < trsL; i++) {
    r = trs[i];
    sels = Q('select', r);
    ya.push([]);
    for (let n = 0, s, q = sels.length; n < q; n++) {
      s = sels[n];
      s.value = 'Yes';
      y = s.value === 'Yes' ? 1 : 0;
      ya[i].push(y);
      s.oninput = () => {
        ya[i][n] = s.value === 'Yes' ? 1 : 0;
        showAverages();
      }
    }
  }

  showAverages();

});
```

```css
* {
  /* set font-size separate to avoid white space issues */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  font: italic 16px Georgia, Garamond, serif;
}


/* added ---------- */

p span {
  color: black;
  font: bold 16px Georgia, Garamond, serif;
}


/* ---------------- */

table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

thead *,
tfoot * {
  font: bold 16px Arial, san-serif;
}

tbody * {
  font: 15px Arial, sans-serif;
}

td,
th {
  width: 90px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #ddd;
}

tfoot>tr>td:not(:last-child):after {
  content: '%';
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8' />
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
  <title>Finding Average</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <p>Finding and Display Average: <span id="element"></span><br><br><br></p>
  </div>
  <!--the total average goes here-->
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Jan</th>
        <th>Feb</th>
        <th>Mar</th>
        <th>Apr</th>
        <th>May</th>
        <th>Jun</th>
        <th>Jul</th>
        <th>Aug</th>
        <th>Sept</th>
        <th>Oct</th>
        <th>Nov</th>
        <th>Dec</th>
        <th>Total Average</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr class="percent_row">
        <td>Response Percent</td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Bought Office Supplies</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Saving's Over $25,000</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Savings</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Over Budget</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Over Budget $10,000</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Over Budget $20,000</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: I would look into session storage https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage and local storage https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage
However sensible data shouldn't be stored inside those since any script can read its content. There should be a database for that.

Comment: as say @FireFighter yes you have to use the session storage or local storage. in your case its local storage

Comment: So if i have a database and when or if the user refresh of close the webpage will it be able to pick and see data base on what the user enter

Comment: so at the beginning of program you see if datas have been saved so if yes you load and save datas when they are modified... you have to code the logic.. if its for lot of users or one user...

Comment: is any example i can look at

Comment: you cant use database in browser client for security reason.only with your server (Ajax request).. you could read https://aurorasolutions.io/html5-local-storage-practical-example/

Comment: so the data the user enters or select will be stored in the local storage corect

Answer (score 1):

The localStorage and sessionStorage properties allow to save key/value pairs in a web browser.

The localStorage object stores data with no expiration date. The data will not be deleted when the browser is closed, and will be available the next day, week, or year.

The localStorage property is read-only.

Example:

```
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

Comment: So if i do  localStorage.setItem("select_row", " ");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("select_row");

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store for example your data `ya` to local storage, you have to stringify the data, because localstorage accepts only **string**:

```
localStorage.setItem("savetab", JSON.stringify(ya));
```

to retrieve data, you do invers:

```
ya = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("savetab"));

after you rebuild your display yes or no for each row/column
```

`ya` is an array of 12 columns and 6 rows so 72 selects

so when you loop over ya, you'll do something like that to reload all selects with data saved:

```
   for(var row = 0; row < 6; row++){
     for(var col = 0; col < 12; col++){
       $("select").eq(row * 12 + col).val(ya[row, col] == 1 ? "Yes" : "No");
     }
   }
```

following your sample:

you execute the `localStorage.setItem` inside `showAverages()`

and before the last line you load the data saved

```
  //restore your data here before calling the function average
  showAverages();

});
```

Comment: This is the first time im doing it so i have no clue where or how to start..i did a lot research last night and found this: https://editor.datatables.net/examples/advanced/localstorage.html

Comment: @TeamKnights see my answer modifed to have an idea to implement the functionality.. localStorage is not functional  (i think) in snippet because the code is sandboxed

Comment: im so sorry im lost an as earlier mention in new to html, jqueary javascript and localstroage